# pass from controller to view in grails

Tags: grails

I am trying to pass from my controller to my view in grails
In my controller i have this:

```
    def index() {
    def user = User.get(springSecurityService.principal.id)
    def children = user.children
    }
```

and in my gsp (view i have this)

```
 <g:each var="child" in="${children}">
    <p>Name: ${child.firstname}</p>
    <p>Author: ${child.lastname}</p>
 </g:each>
```

It does not pick up the children object from my controller i have also tried

```
<% def children = children %>
```

with no luck

can some one please point me in the right direction

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
def index() {
   def user = User.get(springSecurityService.principal.id)
   render(view:'index',model:[children:user.children]) 
}
```

Comment: It's redundant to explicitly render the view that would have been rendered by convention - see the answer from @doelleri for the more standard approach (except for the unnecessary `return` statement)

Comment: Is it so much incorrect? I always do so to prevent hard name dependency.

Comment: You mean to add a hard name dependency :)

Comment: @BurtBeckwith I debated about the return but ended up leaving it in there for clarity. Do you always rely on the implicit return?

Comment: Just to put 2c in here - I've found that if you're wanting the output to be "raw" (no layout applied), you do explicitly require the 'view' argument, because simply passing "layout: null" causes weird results.

Answer (score 5):

By convention, Grails will render the view that matches the controller action that was executed. It will also, by convention, pass as the return value of the action as the view's model. In your case for this to work correctly, you can either explicitly render the view as in @Mr. Cat's answer, or you can return the model like

```
def index() {
    def user = User.get(springSecurityservice.principal.id)
    [children: user.children]
}
```

Groovy implicitly returns the last expression evaluated.